# How to calculate MTD of previous month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I've calculated a MoM variance thanks to this formula:

```
costInBillingCurrency MoM% = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('Usage details'[date]),
    ERROR("Time intelligence quick measures can only be grouped or filtered by the Power BI-provided date hierarchy or primary date column."),
    VAR __PREV_MONTH =
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]),
            DATEADD('Usage details'[date].[Date], -1, MONTH)
        )
    RETURN
        DIVIDE(
            SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]) - __PREV_MONTH,
            __PREV_MONTH
        )
)
```

But in order to make it work I need to use 2 slicers, one on the year and one on the month: [image]

The problem comes when it's mid February and I'm comparing the numbers of the previous month.

This means that I'm comparing, let's say, 15 days of February with 31 days of January.

What I would like to do is to compare the first 15 days of February with the first 15 days of January

If I try to use the [Power BI Time Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380786?src=office&tab=Overview&exp=kyyw) everything brakes.

So I searched for an alternative online and I found this:

- [MoM % by day, handling end of month day difference](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/MoM-by-day-handling-end-of-month-day-difference/m-p/569735)
- [MOM Calculation based on Last Day of Month](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/MOM-Calculation-based-on-Last-Day-of-Month/m-p/2553819)

But they don't work.

How can I compare the first 15 days of this month with the first 15 days of the last month?

Or the first week of this month against the first week of the last month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way:

First create [Last Month](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Last-month-to-date-is-incorrectly-giving-the-whole-previous/m-p/1491065#M28660):

```
Last Month = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), 
    DATEADD(
        FILTER(DATESMTD('Usage details'[date].[Date]), 'Usage details'[date].[Date] < TODAY()),
        -1,
        MONTH))
```

Then create [MoM Same Period Last Month](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UG1WxkBkM48):

```
MoM Same Period Last Month = 

VAR _date = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,DAY(TODAY()))
VAR _maxDate = MAX('Usage details'[date].[Date])
VAR _isEndOfMonth = CALCULATE(MAX('Usage details'[date].[Date]), ALLSELECTED('Usage details')) == _date
VAR _compareDate = 
IF(
    _isEndOfMonth,
    _maxDate,
    MIN(DATE(YEAR(_maxDate), MONTH(_maxDate), DAY(_date)), _maxDate)
)

RETURN
CALCULATE([Last Month],
    DATESMTD(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES('Usage details'[date].[Date]),
            KEEPFILTERS('Usage details'[date] <= _compareDate))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement recently where it's effectively, we want to see production numbers at different points of time to compare against one another.  I set up a calendar table and then added the measures I needed in that table.  For example, this was for showing cases last month that you could use to show over a period of a year, etc.

```
Cases Last Month = CALCULATE('CaseData'[Status Case Count],PREVIOUSMONTH('Calendar'[Date]))
```

taking the same type of theme but not having your dataset, I think you'd want to make sure to have a calendar table and a relationship between the usage table you referenced and the calendar table

then I think the measures look like:
First 15 days comparison:

```
 First_15_Days_MoM% =
VAR CurrentMonthFirst15Days =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            'Calendar'[date],
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ), 1 ),
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ), 15 )
        )
    )
VAR PreviousMonthFirst15Days =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            'Calendar'[date],
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ) - 1, 1 ),
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ) - 1, 15 )
        )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        CurrentMonthFirst15Days - PreviousMonthFirst15Days,
        PreviousMonthFirst15Days
    )
```

First week comparison

````
First_Week_MoM% =
VAR CurrentMonthFirstWeek =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            'Calendar'[date],
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ), 1 ),
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ), 7 )
        )
    )
VAR PreviousMonthFirstWeek =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            'Calendar'[date],
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ) - 1, 1 ),
            DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ) - 1, 7 )
        )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        CurrentMonthFirstWeek - PreviousMonthFirstWeek,
        PreviousMonthFirstWeek
    )

```

might not be exactly right but can see where I'm going with it.
````